# Designing json to save changing data

Tags: java, json, design-patterns

I used to save data from a java application by using JSON.
Basically, the application was a complex form. Each value entered by the user was stored with the field name as the key. I came across a problem when the keys were changed when the application became more complex.
Per example,the application had a field "Optionnal Module", so the JSON looked like:

```
"Optional Module:": "Yes"
```

Then, we added another "Optional Module", so we had

```
"Optional Module 1:": "Yes",
"Optional Module 2:": "No"
```

In the code, I was loading directly the value into the textfield, like `optModule.setText(parsedJSON.get("Optionnal Module"));`

But when I added the second module, it changed to

```
if (parsedJSON.get("Optionnal Module") != null) {
    optModul1.setText(parsedJSON.get("Optionnal Module"));
} else {
    optModul1.setText(parsedJSON.get("Optionnal Module 1"));
}
```

As you can see, the code can get confusing with all changes made to the application.

I can surely use a Facade design pattern to avoid keep the class simple, but I still have another class to maintain...

I then thought I could had an ID instead of the text field name for the JSON key, which is working. Is it a good practice? Is there another way to deal with these changes?

I hope I'm understable.

Thanks!

Comment: To me, its not looking an issue. What you have done seems to be good. I feel, it should be better to collect similar data under a single key.
For example, 
"optional modules": [
        {"module 1": "ABC"},
        {"module 2": "XYZ"}
]

Comment: Sure, but at first, it was not planned to have more than one "optional module", so I didn't made an array...

Comment: Right, working code however you designed is fantastic, but I am looking from json/code readability perspective.